# When the euclidean distance criteria does not work?

Tags: statistics, multivariable-calculus, euclidean-geometry

Good day to everyone. I have a question about classification in presence of additive gaussian noise.

Assuming a predefined reference set of $N$ complex-valued vectors $\vec{x}_r=\{\vec{x}_{r1},\vec{x}_{r2}\ldots \vec{x}_{rN}\}$ and simple gaussian problem 
$$\vec{z}=\vec{x}+\vec{n}$$
where $\vec{x}$ is one of the reference vectors (and is under investigation) and  $\vec{n}$ is the noise vector  with comlpex normal distribution with location parameter $\vec{\mu}$, covariance matrix $\mathbf{\Gamma}$ and the relation matrix $\mathbf{C}$, i.e. $\vec{n}\sim \mathit{CN}(\vec{\mu},\mathbf{\Gamma},\mathbf{C})$.

For simplisity one can assume that $\vec{\mu}=0$ and $\mathbf{C}=0$. The unknown vector $\vec{x}$ is usually  identified with one of the reference vectors $\vec{x}_{ri}$  that provides an extremum of some functional $\varphi(\cdot)$ involving $\vec{z}$ and $\vec{x}_{r}$, i.e. $$\vec{x}=\vec{x}_{rk}: \qquad k=\substack{\textbf{argmin}}_{0\leq j\leq N}\{\varphi(\vec{z},\vec{x}_{rj})\}$$

In literature it is usually stated that the best (optimal) result is achieved with simple euclidean norm $$k=\substack{\textbf{argmin}}_{0\leq j\leq N}\Vert\vec{z}-\vec{x}_{rj}\Vert.$$ And looks to me that nothing can beat it. But is that true?

So the question is: can some one come out with an example of a situation (may be specific vector $\vec{x}$ or something about $\mathbf{\Gamma}$, $\mathbf{C}$, $\vec{\mu}$) when this criteria will not be the best one (optimal)?

Comment: I guess $\textbf{argmin}$ not $\textbf{argmax}$ was meant.